# R - Where element doesn't equal next element in vector

Tags: r

With a vector, say:

```
a <- c(1,1,1, 2,2,2,2, 1,1, 3,3,3,3)
```

I need to know

- at which index values the element values changed
- the element value before/after change

Using the above example, the output would look something like:

```
i before after
3 1      2
7 2      1
9 1      3
```

I suppose I can convert the values into a `data.frame` and lag/shift the column but am wondering if there is a better approach.  I am also trying to avoid looping over the vector, if possible.

I also don't need the results in `data.frame` / spreadsheet format; feel free to propose a different output format.

Comment: `which( diff(a) != 0 )` gives you the changes. Use this as an index to subset `a` to get the values before / after - `a[ which( diff(a) != 0 ) + 1 ]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an option

```
idx <- which(a != c(a[-1], NA))
data.frame(
    i = idx,
    before = a[idx],
    after = a[idx + 1])
#  i before after
#1 3      1     2
#2 7      2     1
#3 9      1     3
```

You can roll everything into a function

```
f <- function(x) {
    idx <- which(x != c(x[-1], NA))
    data.frame(
        i = idx,
        before = x[idx],
        after = x[idx + 1])
}
f(a)
```

giving the same output as above.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  I believe `before = x[idx - 1]` needs to change to `before = x[idx]`.  After making this update, I had what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

```
with(rle(a), data.frame(i = head(cumsum(lengths), -1),
                        before = head(values, -1),
                        after = values[-1]))
#  i before after
#1 3      1     2
#2 7      2     1
#3 9      1     3
```